# jQuery animate problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the animate function in jquery but it is working weird. What is wrong with it?

Here is some code:

here is my html page

```
        <ul class="menu red">
      <li class="current"><a href="javascript:" onclick="nexthome()" target="_self">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:" onclick="nextbio()" target="_self">Bio</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:" onclick="nextport()" target="_self">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:" onclick="nextpric()" target="_self">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:" onclick="nextcon()" target="_self">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

       </div> <!-- End menu -->

      </div> <!-- End header -->
      <div id="content">
      <div id="inner">
            <div id="Home">
            home</div>
            <div id="Bio">bio</div>
            <div id="Portfolio">port</div>
            <div id="Pricing">pric</div>
            <div id="Contact">con</div>
        </div>
```

Here is my style sheet

```
     #content {
       overflow:hidden;
       width: 900px;


     }

     div#inner {
        width: 4515px;
    }

    div#inner div {
        float:left;
        width: 900px;
        margin-right: 3px;

    }
```

here is my script

```
 function nexthome() {

    $('#inner').animate({marginLeft: '0px'}, 1200);
}

 function nextbio() {

    $('#inner').animate({marginLeft: '-1806px'}, 1200);
}

 function nextport() {

    $('#inner').animate({marginLeft: '2709px'}, 1200);
}

 function nextpric() {

    $('#inner').animate({marginLeft: '3612px'}, 1200);
}

 function nextcon() {

    $('#inner').animate({marginLeft: '4515px'}, 1200);
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "working weird." What exactly is happening?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen when you call those functions?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `marginLeft` is probably not the best way to do this... it might work that way, but I think using `left` would be best.

I changed the css to make `#inner` have a relative position and changed the code to set up an object containing the left positions. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/X8L38/1/).

HTML

```
<ul class="menu red">
    <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div> <!-- End menu -->

</div> <!-- End header -->
<div id="content">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="Home">home</div>
        <div id="Bio">bio</div>
        <div id="Portfolio">port</div>
        <div id="Pricing">price</div>
        <div id="Contact">contact</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated CSS:

```
#content {
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 900px;    
}

div#inner {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 5500px;
}

div#inner div {
    float:left;
    width: 900px;
    height: 200px;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
```

Updated script

```
// uses the exact name from the menu
var leftEdge = {
    'Home'      : 0,
    'Bio'       : 903,
    'Portfolio' : 1806,
    'Pricing'   : 2712,
    'Contact'   : 3617
};

$('.menu a').click(function() {
    var name = $(this).text(); // grabs the name from the menu
    $('#inner').animate({
        left: -leftEdge[name] + 'px'
    }, 1200);
    return false;
});
```

I actually have a plugin called [visualNav](https://github.com/Mottie/visualNav) that updates the menu (highlights the visible panel) when a block comes into view, you can check it out if you are interested. The second demo shows the menu working on both horizontally and vertically arrange blocks.